# How to structure rspec data test?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, conventions

### Background

I'm relatively new to Ruby (and RSpec) and I have application code which emits a data object. I want my spec to verify both that the structure of the Hash is correct (i.e. it contains all the necessary keys) and that the data is correct (i.e. that the inputs were correctly merged with default values). Here's a trivialized example:

```
def returns_the_hash
  {
    :foo => "bar",
    :baz => "qux",
    :options => {
      :oof => "rab",
      :zab => "xuq",
    },
  }
end
```

It will be relevant later to note that the entire Hash is deterministic based on inputs (which are available to my spec). The choice I have to make is how expanded or compact to make my assertions. Suppose in this case I'm interested only in the `:foo` and `:options[:zab]` pairs:

### The "explicit" test

**Advantage**: Best separation of intent

**Disadvantages**: Most verbose; introduces a hidden dependency relationship

```
it "should be structured properly" do
  hsh = returns_the_hash
  expect(hsh).to have_key(:foo)
  expect(hsh).to have_key(:options)
  expect(hsh[:options]).to have_key(:zab)
end

it "should merge inputs with default values" do
  hsh = returns_the_hash
  # assumes that the structure is correct
  expect(hsh[:foo]).to eq("bar")
  expect(hsh[:options][:zab]).to eq("xuq")
end
```

### The "implicit" test

**Advantages**: Most concise; easy to maintain

**Disadvantage**: Makes assumptions; combines structure/content testing

```
it "should be well-formed" do
  hsh = returns_the_hash
  # also assumes that the structure is correct; doesn't verify it outright
  expect(hsh[:foo]).to eq("bar")
  expect(hsh[:options][:zab]).to eq("xuq")
end
```

### Question

I would posit that from a coverage standpoint, that these two strategies are virtually equivalent.

Is there a convention (or better yet, provided mechanism) in rspec for testing complex return values for structure and/or content like this? Should I not worry about combining the two concepts (structure and data) and go with the "implicit" test, or is that poor form, and I should keep the two separate as in the "explicit" example?

Or, am I attacking this problem all wrong in the first place and going against the Ruby/Rspec opinionated "way"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the intent of `returns_the_hash`

If it changes and all of a sudden returns

```
{
  :lorem => "ipsum",
  :foo => "bar",
  :baz => "qux",
  :options => {
    :oof => "rab",
    :zab => "xuq",
  },
}
```

Is that a bug that it returned lorem/ipsum or is it ok?

If that indicates a bug, then your **explicit** and **implicit** tests wouldn't catch it, while the **exact** test would catch it.

If that situation is not a bug, then you have more flexibility in deciding how important those other elements are to you and whether it makes sense for the tests to require less maintenance.

It depends on how the data is used. For example, if all the data in the hash eventually shows up to the user, then your tests should be more stringent on what data is actually being returned (the **exact** test.)

Comment: `:baz` and `:options[:oof]` in my example were exactly a case of such "extra" pairs slipping into the Hash (just like your `:lorem` example), which in my case isn't a concern. So, that does rule out the "exact" test. Unfortunately my question remains - is being laboriously meticulous (my "explicit" test) unnecessary? Is combining structure and data (my "implicit" test) poor form?

Comment: Then your "implicit" test is all you need. If `expect(hsh).to have_key(:foo)` fails then `expect(hsh[:foo]).to eq("bar")` would also always fail

Comment: Yes, I realize that, which is actually where my question comes from. I'm looking for guidance (preferably with references) as to which is considered more idiomatic.